# Cross compiling "Hello World" on Mac for Android

Tags: android, go, cross-compiling, cgo

I'm trying to build a standard "Hello, World!" command-line executable for Android. The executable is to be run via `adb shell`.

### 0. The Go (Golang) Source

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, world!")
}
```

### 1A. The Build Command

```sh
$ CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=android GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 go build .
```

### 1B. The Output (Line Breaks Rearranged to Prevent Scrollbars)

```
# github.com/asukakenji/cross
warning: unable to find runtime/cgo.a
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link: running clang failed: exit status 1
ld: warning: ignoring file
    /var/folders/dd/6k6vkzbd6d5803xj9zkjdhmh0000gn/T/go-link-150305609/go.o,
    file was built for unsupported file format
    ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00
      0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 )
    which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64):
    /var/folders/dd/6k6vkzbd6d5803xj9zkjdhmh0000gn/T/go-link-150305609/go.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

### 1C. The Build Command, Again

The following command gives the same result:

```sh
$ env CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=android GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 go build .
```

### 2. The Build Command (Verbose)

I've tried using `"-v"` as mentioned like this:

```sh
$ CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=android GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 go build \
      -x -ldflags "-extldflags -v" .
```

It gives me more than 100 lines of messages, so I don't post it here unless it's necessary. The `go build` command seems to try compiling the source with the `clang` bundled with `Xcode`.

### 3A. The Build Command (Successful, but...)

Given the hint that the wrong compiler is found, I tried to set `$CC` like this:

```sh
$ CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=android GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 \
      CC=/path/to/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/clang go build .
```

`arm-linux-androideabi` is the output from `make_standalone_toolchain.py` (or `make-standalone-toolchain.sh`).

### 3B. The Output

The executable (named `cross`) is successfully built, with the following messages:

```
# github.com/asukakenji/cross
warning: unable to find runtime/cgo.a
```

I tried `adb push` it and run it with `adb shell` on Android, it worked fine.

### My Questions

1. Why does it need a C compiler? Doesn't Go cross-compile out-of-the-box?
2. When building for Linux (instead of Android), the compilation works fine:

   ```sh
   $ CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build .
   ```

   Why?
3. The `go build` command keeps looking for `runtime/cgo.a`, even when I didn't use CGO in the source code, and even when I set `CGO_ENABLED=0`. How can I get rid of the warning? How is it harmful not having one?

Comment: To make things easy, I think you need Android NDK.  clang should work too,  but it's not offical for Android native programming, need lots of configurations maybe.

Comment: As stated above, I already successfully compiled the code using Android NDK. The question is why it is needed. When I target "Linux amd64", a cross compiler is never needed. What makes the difference?

Comment: I guess something related `-D__ARM_ANDROID__ -DHAVE_PTHREADS` which we always added in NDK building.

Comment: I am afraid that you missed the point. I understand very well that the NDK can get the job done. I just wonder why a C compiler is needed. As far as I know, the Golang compiler compiles source to binary without the need of another compiler, unless CGO is used. I have successfully built these on a Mac, all without any external tools: "darwin amd64" (host), "linux 386", "linux amd64", "windows 386", "windows amd64". But why is "android arm" an exception? The point is not the flags used, the point is why a C compiler is needed at the first place!

Comment: I know your point. But C-things (compiler/stdlib/macros/headers/#pragma) depends platform badly. Another C compiler hardly work with the android C-things. Still it's my guess, not dig deep.

Comment: I didn't write a single line of C code here.

Comment: some old http://blog.hashbangbash.com/2014/04/linking-golang-statically/

Comment: Thanks! But I'm **NOT** using CGO here, and that's exactly why I wonder why a C compiler is needed. Sorry, but have you read my question?

Answer (score 5):

if you run that code you find the android as an official target platform 
listed as GOOS/GOARCH

```
$go tool dist list
```

Comment: Sure, it is now, in go1.10.3. The question is two years old.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yeah for sure, I add it for the new comers reference.

Answer (score 4):

Android isn't official target platform for cross-compilation. If all you need are command-line executables then you can set GOOS=linux because android is a linux under the hood, else take a look at https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile

Answer (score 2):

The cgo requirement might be because go requires libc for DNS lookups on Android: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8877

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk) to compile for android, you can download it from the link, or from [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio):

[image]

Then you can find the compilerlink in the route as below:

```bash
Last login: Fri Sep  4 09:25:16 on console

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
Hasans-Air:~ hajsf$ pwd
/Users/hajsf
Hasans-Air:~ hajsf$ cd Library
Hasans-Air:Library hajsf$ cd android
Hasans-Air:android hajsf$ cd sdk
Hasans-Air:sdk hajsf$ cd ndk
Hasans-Air:ndk hajsf$ ls
21.3.6528147
Hasans-Air:ndk hajsf$ cd 21.3.6528147
Hasans-Air:21.3.6528147 hajsf$ cd toolchains
Hasans-Air:toolchains hajsf$ cd llvm
Hasans-Air:llvm hajsf$ cd prebuilt
Hasans-Air:prebuilt hajsf$ ls
darwin-x86_64
Hasans-Air:prebuilt hajsf$ cd darwin-x86_64
Hasans-Air:darwin-x86_64 hajsf$ cd bin
Hasans-Air:bin hajsf$ pwd
/Users/hajsf/Library/android/sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin
```

Then you can use the one reflection:

1. Architecture you want to build your android app for, like `aarch64`
2. Android API you want to compile for, like `Android 30`

You can see full list of available options there, and you can select the one you want like `aarch64-linux-android30-clang`

If you are at `Windows 10` you'll find it at:

```bash
"C:\Users\${user}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\${NKD_version}\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\aarch64-linux-android30-clang"
```

There are 4 available linkers which are:

```bash
//CC_FOR_TARGET=/Users/hajsf/Library/android/sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android30-clang
//CC_FOR_TARGET=/Users/hajsf/Library/android/sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android30-clang
//CC_FOR_TARGET=/Users/hajsf/Library/android/sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android30-clang
//CC_FOR_TARGET=/Users/hajsf/Library/android/sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi30-clang
```

After that only you can do cross-compiling, as:

```bash
$ CGO_ENABLED=1
$ GOOS=android
$ GOARCH=arm64
$ CC_FOR_TARGET=/Users/hajsf/Library/android/sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android30-clang
$ go build -buildmode=c-shared -o lib-aarch64-android30.so lib.go
```

And a simple `cgo` file `lib.go` could be:

```golang
package main

import "C"
import "fmt"

//export HelloWorld
func HelloWorld() {
    fmt.Printf("hello world from GO\n")
}

//export GetKey
func GetKey() *C.char {
    theKey := "123-456-789"
    return C.CString(theKey)
}

func main() {}
```

[image]

As shown compilation completed successfully, and both `lib-aarch64-android30.so` and `ib-aarch64-android30.h` had been generated without any error.

Quick note, not to go far from the scope of the question, if you return a string, then the return value from this function *must* be explicitly freed in the C code if if you call it from `C` code, but as you call it from garbage collector environment, Java/Kotlin you do not want to worry about it.

If freeing the allocated buffer isn't convenient, its common to fill a buffer provided by the caller:

```
func GetKey(buff *C.char, n int) int
```

If you can allocate the memory but don't want to handle C strings, you can insert the buffer into a pointer and return the size.

```
func GetKey(buff **C.char) int
```